# How do new CarrIOTA nodes actually discover an existing one?

Tags: neighbors, nelson

Say someone creates a new CarrIOTA node, where does that new node begin to look for existing ones?

Also, what's the difference between CarrIOTA and Nelson?

Comment: [CarrIOTA](http://www.carriota.com/) is a WiP "finance/wallet manager" app. Nelson is an add-on for IRI nodes that manages your neighbors. What do you mean by CarrIOTA node?